# pod update --verbose & pod install --verbose not completing, hangs

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

**pod update --verbose not completing, hangs .**

```
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/4/b/GoogleToolboxForMac/2.1.2/GoogleToolboxForMac.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/4/b/GoogleToolboxForMac/2.1.3/GoogleToolboxForMac.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/4/b/GoogleToolboxForMac/2.1.4/GoogleToolboxForMac.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/4/b/GoogleToolboxForMac/2.2.0/GoogleToolboxForMac.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/4/b/GoogleToolboxForMac/2.2.1/GoogleToolboxForMac.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/4.4.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/4.3.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/4.2.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.9.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.8.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.6.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.5.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.3.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.3.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.2.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.8.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/5.8.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.9.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.8.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.6.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.5.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/3.4.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.2.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.2.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/5.4.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ALLIPONews' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'                 #Prerequisite Libraries and Analytics
    #pod 'Firebase/AdMob'               #AdMob
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'            #Cloud Messaging /
    pod 'Firebase/Database'             #Realtime Database
    pod 'Firebase/Invites'              #Invites
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'         #Dynamic Links
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'         #Remote Config
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'                 #Authentication
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'              #Storage
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'          #Performance Monitoring
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'            #Firestore
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'SDWebImage/WebP'
    pod 'SDWebImage/GIF'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    pod 'PageMenu'
    pod 'RMessage'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'FreshchatSDK'
    pod 'TwitterCore'
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'SwiftLocation'
    pod 'SwiftDate'
    pod 'GzipSwift'
    pod 'DataCompression'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'PDFReader'

    #Analytics
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Mixpanel-swift'

    #Contacts
    #pod 'APAddressBook/Swift'
    pod 'SwiftAddressBook'

    #Logging
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'

    #UI
    pod 'Material'
    pod 'Motion'
    #pod 'LTMorphingLabel'
    #pod 'CountdownLabel'
    pod 'expanding-collection'              #Ramotion
    pod 'paper-onboarding'                  #Ramotion
    #pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController'      #Ramotion
    #pod 'FoldingCell'                      #Ramotion
    pod 'SwiftMessages'
    #pod 'MaterialComponents'               #Google
    pod 'Armchair'
    pod 'UICircularProgressRing'
    #pod 'CariocaMenu', '~> 2.0'

    #Debugging
    pod 'GDPerformanceView-Swift'
    pod 'FlowUpIOSSDK', '~> 0.0.3'

    #Animation
    pod 'lottie-ios'

    #User Data
    pod 'DeviceKit'
    pod 'TrueSDK'

    #Charts
    #pod 'ScrollableGraphView'

    #Upgrades
    pod 'Appgrades'
    pod 'Siren'

    #Javascript
    pod 'WKWebViewJavascriptBridge', '~> 1.1.0'

    #Chat
    pod 'SendBirdSDK'

  # Pods for ALL-IPO-NEWS

  target 'ALLIPONewsTests' do
      inherit! :complete
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried running `pod repo update` to make sure you have the most recent pods, before doing pod update? BTW: thats a lot of pods!

Comment: Tried. No Impact. I have tried pod deintegrate and pod install --verbose and it runs forever at 99% cpu

Answer (score 2):

Since CocoaPods 1.8+, the default spec repo changed to the CDN instead of Git. This has been problematic for quite a lot of devs.

You can configure CocoaPods to go back to using the Git spec repo by adding `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` to the top of your `Podfile`, which may help.